# Start with letter, must container letter and numbers

Tags: regex, vbscript

I trying for hours to find a regex which match this creteria:

Need to find a big text the following:

- Start with 2 digits
- Ends with a " "
- exact 7 characters
- Must contain digit and letters
- letters only capital

Here a text exampel: (need to match the "159C5F"

```
AT exempt acc to §§ 4 Nr. 1A UStG iVm 6 USTG
                                                                                                                            254,49/100L    977,23
159C5F Magnatec St-St 0W-30 D, 20L E4                                                                                                   0,00%
Commodity Code :
```

Here are a few of my tries:

```
(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})
[0-9]{2}\S*[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}
[0-9]\S*[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}
[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}
```

Comment: _"I trying for hours"_ Please include what you've tried so far. Also, please explain how `159C5F` follows the _"exact 7 digits"_ rule.

Comment: I habe added 4 examples I have tries, but all match also with other parts in the text (only numbers for example)

Comment: What programming language or regex flavor are you using?

Comment: also added the rules, I use vbscript

Comment: @Zam89 Try [like this](https://regex101.com/r/VqV08s/3) to get the stuff after. If it's always at start of line you can also replace the initial `\b` with `^` for better performance [like this](https://regex101.com/r/VqV08s/4) in multline mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you may use something like this:

```
\b\d\d(?=\S*?[A-Z]\S*?\s)[A-Z0-9]{4}\s
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VqV08s/2).

**Some notes:**

- If you don't want to capture the space at the end, you may replace the final `\s` with a Lookahead (i.e., `(?=\s)`).
- If you want to accept only the ASCII space character and no other whitespace characters, you may use `[ ]` instead of `\s` in both occurrences.

Comment: This is perfect :) maybe you have also a solution for m next problem:
I need this regex fo get the currect row, but I really need is the description behind that value 'Magnatec St-St 0W-30 D, 20L E4'
So I have tried this: '"(\d\d(?=\S*?[A-Z]\S*?\s)[A-Z0-9]{4}\s)(.?)+    ' and get the second value, but it is always empty

Comment: @Zam89 If you have a new question, you should post it [as a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)

Comment: will do in 90 min :)

Answer (score 2):

You might use word boundaries and a positive lookahead to assert the space at the end but not match it to match to get only `159C5F`

```
\b\d{2}(?=[A-Z0-9]{4} )[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `\d{2}` Match 2 digits
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[A-Z0-9]{4}`  Match 4 times any of the listed followed by a space
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*` Match 0+ times A-Z0-9 with at least a single uppercase char
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iwq9XX/1/)